# Calling alert view from another class, but one is not in hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, hierarchy

I'm trying to call function from one class in view controller:

```
var rate = RateMyApp.sharedInstance 
rate.showRatingAlert()
```

and in RateMyApp class I call alert view:

```
 var window: AnyObject = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!;
        var vc = window.rootViewController;
      vc?!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, the alert is not shown and there is a kind of warning:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x15fe3dcf0> on <drawtext.ViewController: 0x16002a800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

That happens from time to time, if one hides the app and then opens it again several times, the alert sometimes is shown.

What can cause such strange behavior?

Comment: not, it is not, in your case the problem was connected with calling in viewdidappear/viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using UIAlertController it should be presented form the topmost ViewController in the view hierarchy.

so i suggest:

```
var rate = RateMyApp.sharedInstance 
rate.showRatingAlert(self)
```

In RateMyApp class:

```
func showRatingAlert(sender:UIViewController){
//..... your UIAlertController here
 sender.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

On a more general note, the func `presentViewController(:_)` should be called only from the top-most View Controller.

You can create an extension for it like so:

```
extension UIViewController {
  @warn_unused_result
  static func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }

    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController

        if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController where top.view.window != nil {
            return topViewController(top)
        } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }

    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }

    if let splitVC = base as? UISplitViewController {
        if let lastVC = splitVC.viewControllers.last {
            return topViewController(lastVC)
        }
        else {
            return splitVC
        }
    }

    if let lastChildVC = base?.childViewControllers.last {
        return topViewController(lastChildVC)
    }

    return base
   }
}
```

You can call the alert as follows:

```
func showRatingAlert() {
   if let vc = UIViewController.topViewController() {
      vc.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be solved:

```
     var window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
           // var vc = window.rootViewController!!.presentingViewController

        var vc = window.rootViewController;
        while (vc!.presentedViewController != nil)
        {
            vc = vc!.presentedViewController;
        }

      vc?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

looks like Chetan's solution

Answer (score 0):

Do it when the window is up

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    var window: AnyObject = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!;
    var vc = window.rootViewController;
    vc?!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: I checked that, same problem

Comment: where you call function  in view controller?

Comment: in several parts, pressing a button, for example
 @IBAction func rateb3(sender: AnyObject) {
       
        
        var rate = RateMyApp.sharedInstance
       // self.view.addSubview(rate.view)
        rate.appID = "972360624"
        rate.trackAppUsage()
        rate.showRatingAlert()
       
    }

Answer (score 0):

As per my thought you just need

1. Get top most viewcontroller [currently presented]
2. Present your alert.

To Get Topmost View Controller

[This is obj C code. Please make efforts to convert in swift]

```
-(UIViewController*)topViewController {
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

-(UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

Then

UIViewController *topController = [self topViewController];

Now present your alert on topController.

Sorry i can't deliver you Swift Code. But Hope this is enough to hint.